# How do you add images to an AVD emulator in Android Studio/Wear OS

Tags: android-studio, wear-os

Developing an app using Android Studio that uses the PickVisualMediaRequest.

How can I put images on the emulator so the picker can find them so I can test that feature?

Comment: I think u can just drag the image to the emulator window to add it

Comment: I tried dragging to a number of places, but didn't seem to work.  Do you know what the drop area is?

Comment: The device screen or press shift twice and type "Device file" and add the file there... the emulator must be running!